# jQuery image slider loads all images at once

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery image slider on the header section of my website that displays images periodically in an automated sliding motion. Now the problem is when you load the page for the 1st time(nothing is cached), it loads all the images in the slider at once and it aligns the images one on top of the other on the webpage(one div on top of another), so you see all the images at once the moment the page loads. It doesn't look very professional. Is there maybe a onpageload() function of sorts that can prevent all the images from showing at once or that can load them first in the background before showing them? This is especially a problem with lower internet speeds...My website: http://v4m.mobi

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give your images a style of `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` and then change their styles back to `display:[block/inline/etc]` or `visibility:visible` on `$(window).load()`.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#myImage1').css('visibility','visible');
    $('#myImage2').css('visibility','visible');
    //etc
});
```

Comment: Hi DC_. Thank you for your answer, but I would like to know, how exactly do I apply the visibility:visible on the images with the document.ready() function ? Since the images in the html are loaded before the javascript

Comment: $(window).load as suggested by the other answerer is probably better for this actually.
I edited my answer with some sample code.

Comment: Hey @DC_ your code worked! I would like to add one more thing. If we have many images then instead of changing the visibility of each image, we can change the visibility of the parent div/ul/container of the images itself.

Answer (score 0):

Preload your images or use jQuery and load your code with window.load().

```
$(window).load(function(){  
// runs after images are loaded  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I assume your method above uses Ajax?

Comment: I tried the $(window).load(function(){  }); function, but it still loads the images 1st thing. It loads the html table containing the images first and then the jquery and css. I also tried the following(http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/28/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) but no help really, especially with slow internet speeds.

Comment: I looked at your site but I don't see you loading anything with window.load. Plus you have a chunk of code halfway down the page that ends in a head tag:`<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.quickFlip').quickFlip();
});
</script>
</head>`. Your window.load (and even document.ready) should be in the head of your page.

Comment: Ok I tried this method and it works. But there is one big problem: the images it 'hides' until the page has loaded, is my main banner images.They are now shown last. Now these are my 'hit' images, I want visitors to see these images first, but I don't want the images to load all at once, one on top of the other at the first glance. The images are all contained in a table, inside a parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not simply do:

```
.slideshow img {
    display: none;
}

.slideshow img:first-child {
    display: block;
}
```

They may or may not all load in at once depending on the browser but at least only one will be visible. Plus you have the non-JavaScript fallback of the first image being visible.

If you need older browser support create some kind of "visible" class and add it to the first image element.