# Why do the images in my sliders load all at once?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I don't get it. Lazy image loading is enabled by default and I even tried this JavaScript from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973642/jquery-image-slider-loads-all-images-at-once) (apparently that fixed it. Also maybe it doesn't work for me because I don't use jquery?). I also tried `content-visibility: hidden` until I realized that Firefox or Safari doesn't even support it... (why?????)

```
let element = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

Array.from(element).forEach(i => {
    i.style.display = "block";
});
```

I think the other images on the other slider still don't load until I've scrolled to it so there does seem to be some kind of optimization? I honestly can't tell anymore. To me it still looks like they all try to load all at once when I clear my cache & refresh. My goal is to just load the images once they're actually displayed and scrolled onto in the slider but I can't get it to work. The images are quite large and I should downsize them but this would still help either way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using CSS.
Provide `display: none;` to all the default slides and apply `display: block;` only to the active slide through CSS. This will solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what my JavaScript does? What do you mean by only to the active slide? As in if I've clicked on it or like, if it's in my viewport?

Comment: Can you provide a demonstration of your slider? So that I can look more into it and give a solution to you.

Comment: Basically, it's a div where inside is a bunch of pictures. It's height is & width is fixed and overflow set to auto so you can slide left and right to view all the pictures. Unfortunately I  can't get you a live example ATM but hopefully this explanation is enough because that's literally all it is.